# Spring Security and OAuth2: can I add ClientRegistration to ClientRegistrationRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

It is fairly straightforward to configure a Spring Boot application to work with a single OAuth2 authorization server. My application needs to be able to get authentication tokens from multiple authorization servers that are not known in advance. I need to find a way to manage them in a dynamic way.

From what I can see `ClientRegistrationRepository` requires `ClientRegistration` at instantation. And `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` requires `ClientRegistrationRepository` and `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService`. Examples that I have seen suppose that you will configure `ClientRegistration` once and for all and build the client starting from there. I will need to be able to add and remove OAuth2 authentication servers and I don't know their details in advance.

Is spring-security usable for this task? How would I organize working with dynamic oauth2 servers? Is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm puzzled: do you want to add **authorization-servers** with **clients** registration?

Multi-tenancy (several authorization-servers) is:

- easy to achieve if all access-tokens are JWTs: you can read `iss` claim to know which public key to verify token signature with (or even to which server submit token for introspection, but this is a edge case)
- complicated, dirty and inefficient if tokens are opaque: you'll have to provide an introspector which submits each token to each authorization-server, picking the only positive response (if any).

Solution hereafter is not completly dynamic (multi-tenancy declared in properties => restart needed to add new issuers) and applies to JWT decoders only.

I have spring-boot starter libs which support multi-tenancy for JWTs. Samples [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples):

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/master
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[1].location=https://bravo-ch4mp:8443/realms/master
# more properties per issuer for authorities mapping
```

You can browse [source code](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/config/synchronised/AddonsWebSecurityBeans.java) to see how this is achieved:

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver));
```

with

```java
    @Bean
    JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver(
            OAuth2ResourceServerProperties auth2ResourceServerProperties,
            SpringAddonsSecurityProperties securityProperties,
            Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken> authenticationConverter) {
        final Optional<IssuerProperties> bootIssuer = Optional.ofNullable(auth2ResourceServerProperties.getJwt())
                .flatMap(jwt -> Optional
                        .ofNullable(StringUtils.hasLength(jwt.getIssuerUri()) ? jwt.getIssuerUri() : null))
                .map(issuerUri -> {
                    final IssuerProperties issuerProps = new IssuerProperties();
                    issuerProps.setJwkSetUri(
                            Optional.ofNullable(auth2ResourceServerProperties.getJwt().getJwkSetUri())
                                    .map(uri -> StringUtils.hasLength(uri) ? uri : null)
                                    .map(jwkSetUri -> {
                                        try {
                                            return new URI(jwkSetUri);
                                        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                                            throw new RuntimeException(
                                                    "Malformed JWK-set URI: %s".formatted(jwkSetUri));
                                        }
                                    }).orElse(null));
                    return issuerProps;
                });

        final Map<String, AuthenticationManager> jwtManagers = Stream
                .concat(bootIssuer.stream(), Stream.of(securityProperties.getIssuers()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(issuer -> issuer.getLocation().toString(), issuer -> {
                    final JwtDecoder decoder = issuer.getJwkSetUri() != null
                            && StringUtils.hasLength(issuer.getJwkSetUri().toString())
                                    ? NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(issuer.getJwkSetUri().toString()).build()
                                    : JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuer.getLocation().toString());
                    final var provider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(decoder);
                    provider.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter::convert);
                    return provider::authenticate;
                }));

        log.debug(
                "Building default JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver with: ",
                auth2ResourceServerProperties.getJwt(),
                Stream.of(securityProperties.getIssuers()).toList());

        return new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver((AuthenticationManagerResolver<String>) jwtManagers::get);
    }
```